# How to enable timeout in pipeline based on a condition?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've a Jenkins pipeline with following stage -

```
stage('Test') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    //some code here
                }
            }
        }
```

Here I've set timeout but there will be one parameter say `TimeoutEnabled`. If it has value `true`, only then use timeout restrictions otherwise there will be no timeout restriction for the stage.

How can I handle this efficiently without having duplicated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stage('Test') {
    options {
        timeout(time: (params.TIMEOUT_ENABLED ? 5 : 99999999), unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
    steps {
        script {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}
```